# E2E test environment in microservices

Tags: testing, architecture, microservices, e2e-testing, e2e

My backend project includes some microservices and I have a frontend project.
I have a development branch and a production branch on GitLab. each backend service has its repository environment and database. I have pipelines for my different environments(development and production branches). my backend services and front services have unit tests and integration tests and run independently.
I wrote e2e with selenium and ran manually but it's not best practice.
my E2E test interacts with front and back services and db together.
I have some questions about E2E testing:

1. I want to run an E2E test in isole environment don't touch the developed database.
2. Can I automate the E2E test when the back and front releases a new version?
3. Do I need to create another repository to run the E2E test?
4. When should the E2E test run? (every merge to development?)

What is the good architecture for implementing this architecture in CI and automating the E2E test?

Comment: Hi, this seems like several questions in one. Happy to give advice though. Do you have a tool preference? Do you use Azure for CI? Etc

Comment: @OPSM I don't use azure cloud or other cloud services